# how to compile function in C code using RcppEigen

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, do.call

I am very new to Rcpp, or more specifically RcppEigen, and struggling with how to use RcppEigen to compile C++ function. Here is the C++ code in which some problems maybe exist.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace Rcpp;

double MatOp(const Map<MatrixXd> X, Map<MatrixXd> Y)
{ 

  int n=X.rows();
  int p=X.cols();
  //int nY=Y.cols();
  MatrixXd I(n,n);
  I.setIdentity(n,n);
  double SSE=(Y.transpose()*(I-X*(X.transpose()*X).inverse()*X.transpose())*Y).determinant();
  return (n*log(SSE/n)+log(n)*p);
}
```

And here is R code,

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/LJH/Documents"
> RcppEigen.package.skeleton("PfCRT")

> RCppEigen_IcPf_R <- function(X,Y) {
+   .Call('TestInRcppEigen',X,Y,PACKAGE = 'PfCRT')
+ }
> 
> prompt(RCppEigen_IcPf_R)
```

`.Rcheck` file is,

```
* installing *source* package 'PfCRT' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m32 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppEigen/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c TestInRcppEigen.cpp -o TestInRcppEigen.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PfCRT.dll tmp.def TestInRcppEigen.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
installing to C:/Users/LJH/Documents/PfCRT.Rcheck/PfCRT/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppEigen/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c TestInRcppEigen.cpp -o TestInRcppEigen.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PfCRT.dll tmp.def TestInRcppEigen.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
installing to C:/Users/LJH/Documents/PfCRT.Rcheck/PfCRT/libs/x64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (PfCRT)
```

Then I do this,

```
> library(PfCRT)
> X1 <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,
+                0,2,0,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,3,1,0,
+                0,3,1,0,0,3.01),20,4,byrow=TRUE)
> Y <- matrix(c(50,51,52,54,53,60,59,65,67,70,70,73,74,78,82,80,87,84,88,92),20,1)
> 
> RCppEigen_IcPf_R(X1,Y)
Error in .Call("TestInRcppEigen", X, Y, PACKAGE = "PfCRT") : 
  "TestInRcppEigen" not available for .Call() for package "PfCRT"
```

Error occurs, so I guess something wrong in `double MatOp(const Map<MatrixXd> X, Map<MatrixXd> Y)` function in C++. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ function is called "MatOp":

```
double MatOp(const Map<MatrixXd> X, Map<MatrixXd> Y)
```

but instead you call "TestInRcppEigen":

```
.Call('TestInRcppEigen',X,Y,PACKAGE = 'PfCRT')
```

which gets the error

```
Error in .Call("TestInRcppEigen", X, Y, PACKAGE = "PfCRT") : 
  "TestInRcppEigen" not available for .Call() for package "PfCRT"
```

which is correct: you did not provide a `TestInRcppEigen`.

Either provide `TestInRcppEigen` (by renaming 'MatOp' to it) or call `MatOp`.

None of this has anything to do with RcppEigen per se, you're simply getting lost in the weeds of how to call C++ from R.  Look at the Rcpp Attributes vignette -- it can really help and simplify.

Comment: well I corrected `double TestInRcppEigen(const Map<MatrixXd> X, Map<MatrixXd> Y)`, there are still 2 warnings and 2 noted in 00check.log. `* checking if this is a source package ... NOTE
Found the following apparent object files/libraries:
  src-i386/PfCRT.dll src-i386/TestInRcppEigen.o src-x64/PfCRT.dll
  src-x64/TestInRcppEigen.o
Object files/libraries should not be included in a source package.`

Comment: `* checking for executable files ... WARNING
Found the following executable files:
  src-i386/PfCRT.dll
  src-i386/TestInRcppEigen.o
  src-x64/PfCRT.dll
Source packages should not contain undeclared executable files.`

Comment: `* checking Rd files ... NOTE
prepare_Rd: PfCRT-package.Rd:31-33: Dropping empty section \seealso`        `* checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ... WARNING
Found the following sources/headers with CR or CRLF line endings:
  src/TestInRcppEigen.cpp
Some Unix compilers require LF line endings.`

Comment: My [pkgKitten](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/pkgkitten.html) package from CRAN helps create package without such notes, but I need to update RcppEigen to use it ...